# Python change path inside submodule?

Tags: python

I have this project structure:

```
- main.py
- app_a/
  - __init__.py
  - app.py
  - stubs/
    - app.py
- tests/
  - test_app_a.py
```

in `main.py`, there is:

`from app_a.app import foo`

this works fine. 
However, when running in test environment(which can be checked by a env variable), I need `main.py` to import from a stub module (which is in `app_a/stubs/app.py`) instead of the real `app_a/app.py`.

Notice that I can't change `main.py` itself, I can just change the environment before it runs.

How can I implement this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write as follows in main.py

```
if env:
    from app_a.app import foo
else:
    from app_a.stubs.app import foo
```

Comment: I can't change `main.py`

Comment: If you can't change main.py at all, I think you can add an if-else about foo in app_a/app.py so that main.py will import different foo according to env.

Answer (score 0):

If you could move `app_a` and `tests` folder to different location (other than script execution directory and Python search path), you could have same code and import different modules using `PYTHONPATH`. Now, if you want to run code, set `app_a` path to PYTHONPATH and if you are running tests, set `app_a\stubs` to PYTHONPATH. In the code you can have `from app import foo' for both.

Other approach is when you import app_a.app, stubs.app is already it's part of it; handle this in code.